# ”Demand in/on/for something”

Tags: word-choice, nouns, prepositions, collocation

I am not sure whether to use *in*, *on*, or *for* after the word *demand* in the following sentence:

> The continuing demand on high-quality software that is reusable and
>   easy to maintain and modify after it has been released was a driving
>   force throughout the 1980’s

How should one deal with this *demand in/on/for* issue in general?

Comment: The title rarely says it all. I'd venture to say it may depend on context. Workers on strike may demand higher wages; a toddler in the middle of a tantrum may demand a new toy; my job may make demands on me. I think you should provide some more concrete examples to help us answer your question.

Comment: @J.R. you are right .. I've edited my post

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In that sentence, you would use *demand for*.

You use *demand for* when some entity has want of a resource, as in *supply-and-demand* economics. Examples would include a high demand *for* candy canes at Christmastime, or a high demand *for* beachfront cottages during the summertime.

*Demand on* is used when a situation is challenging, difficult, or pressure-packed for some entity. For example, at some restaurants, there is a high demand *on* the kitchen staff during the noontime lunch hour.

In some cases, both could be used, although the meaning would be different. For example:

> At tax season, there is a high demand on accountants.

means that accountants work long hours during tax season, but:

> At tax season, there is a high demand for accountants.

means that many people hire accountants at tax time.

Answer (score 4):

*Demand for* is almost certainly what you want here. It means that lots of people wanted it. *Demand on* means that some kind of pressure or strain was being put on the software. I can't think of any circumstances in which it would be necessary to say *demand in high-quality software*.

Answer (score 2):

"Demand for" in that sentence.

Software may have demands placed on it, it may be popular and in demand, but describing a market desire would be "for", I would think.

Answer (score 2):

In general you must use context and intent to choose the correct preposition.

*Demand* ***for*** *high-quality software* means that consumers are demanding it; they want to buy it.

*Demand* ***on*** *high-quality software* talks about the performance expectations people have for the software.

*Demand* ***in*** would only be used when talking about a category of something.  *Demand in the consumer software segment has increased by 50% over the last two months.*

Answer (score 0):

ON DEMAND = The cheque(or anything) has to be given ON DEMAND (means as soon as it is wanted/demanded by somebody else)

IN DEMAND = The "I-Phone 5" is in demand (means people want it a lot)

..this is what as far as I know