# Prepositions for the word "placement" or "clinical placement"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

Which of these is correct?

- I went to cardiac ward **in** my first clinical placement.
- I went to cardiac ward **for** my first clinical placement.
- I went to cardiac ward **on** my first clinical placement.

Also, is it better to say I went in or I went to?

Comment: Where do you want to use the sentence? Context can be everything for preposition use, and a job application context can be far from a hospital-based story context, for example.

Comment: Let's just say I'm telling someone about my first hospital clinical placement.

Comment: "**on** my first clinical placement" sounds right based both on instinct as well as empirical data. ("student nurses on clinical placement in the paediatric ...")

Comment: There's a Q&A about ['for/in/on prepositions'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95746/246019) that explains how context and intent affect the choice. -- Also you *could* say: "I went in the ...", "I went to the ...", ***but*** don't forget that "I went in to the ..." (and not repeat **in**), "I went for the ... in/for/on ...", "I went on the ... in/for/on ..." is also possible.

Comment: "for" suggests that was the only or main thing done as the placement, while "in" or "on" could be just a part of the placement.

Answer (score 0):

If this was just describing a past event to a friend, for example, the second would be a good choice:

- I went to cardiac ward for my first clinical placement.

It still needs so work, as 'ward' is a count noun and if left without an article or anything will default to the uncount noun:

- to the cardiac ward

Finally, 'went' is rather a single-use verb, it lacks the feeling of a repeated action. So we could use a different ploy:

> I was on the cardiac ward for my....

Comment: Can you also say I went to the cardiac ward for my first placement? or should I say I went on the cardiac ward for my first placement?

Comment: 'went to' suggests a single visit, while 'went on' is unlikely and more likely to be use in situations like: 'I went on a bicycle'.